# RegEx Skip last part of a string if it has a forbidden word

Tags: regex

For a couple of example strings I'd like to strip the end of the string if the parentheses contain a forbidden word.

Example list of strings:

```
Test House (selled)
Seahouse (selled)
Motorbike (unconfirmed)
Bike (very good)
```

I have a list of forbidden words: 'selled' and 'unconfirmed'

Currently, I have a javascript function which would return this list:

```
Test House
Seahouse
Motorbike
Bike (very good)
```

The function just uses a simple regex with two capture groups:

```
( \(([a-z0-9\- ]+)\))$
```

... and if group 2 equals a forbidden word, than I strip group 1 from the string.

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this way harder than it needs to be.

```js
var d = $("div"),
    str = d.html();

str = str.replace(/ \((selled|unconfirmed)\)/g, "");

d.html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Test House (selled)<br>
Seahouse (selled)<br>
Motorbike (unconfirmed)<br>
Bike (very good)<br>
  </div>
```